# Not able to find Xamarin.Forms Project Template in Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am not able to find Project Template to build Xamarin Forms apps in my recently installed Visual Studio 2017 Professional IDE. What templates I can see in "Cross-Platform" section is as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I am not able to get the required template?

Answer (score 1):

From Visual Studio 2017 onwards you need to specify what kinds of development you want to do in the installer. To add Xamarin, simply run the installer again, choose the 'Modify' option on the start screen, and then check the box for 'Mobile Development with .NET' (you'll see the Xamarin logo next to it).

That will add support for Xamarin projects to your installation.

Comment: Hi. I ran the installer again and modified it. I have already checked on the 'Mobile Development with .NET' and installed the corresponding components. But on the visible components, I am still not able to see Xamarin.Forms. There is only one option checked known as "Xamarin Workbooks". Thats it.

Comment: OK, just had a chance to blow up your screenshot and decipher what's on there. To create a Xamarin.Forms app, select "Cross-Platform App (Xamarin)". After filling in the project name, path etc. you'll get to another screen where you can specify what kind of Xamarin project you want to create - Forms or native, PCL or shared.

Comment: Well doing so i didnt get any option for creating the app neither on Forms/Native nor PCL/Shared. It just created a project on native type for me.